# Using __call to preprocess method calls to a class. How do I apply this for nested method calls?

Tags: php, reflection

I'm using the php __call on a wrapper class for several classes.

```
class Wrapper {
  public function __construct($obj) {...}

  public function __call($methodName, $params) {
    $this->preprocessSomeStuff();

    // call the original object's method
    $sourceMethod = new ReflectionMethod($this->obj, $methodName);
    return $sourceMethod->invokeArgs($this->obj, $params);
  }
```

This works great for the initial call, but doesn't work if the $obj has a nested method call, e.g.

```
class Thing {
  public function doStuff() {
    $this->doMoreStuff();
  }  

  public function doMoreStuff() {...}
}
```

With this object, calling:

```
$wrappedThing = new Wrapper(new Thing());
// preprocessing applied for doStuff(), not applied for doMoreStuff()
$wrappedThing->doStuff();
```

Comment: Well, yes, it won't do that. How nested do you want to go? Every call to every function, including `substr` and such, needs to be preprocessed? It'd help if you could show some more specific example of what kind of processing you need to do.

Comment: I'd like for my preprocess to run for every method defined in the object I pass into it. I don't think a `substr` would ever get preprocessed with the code I've written (since `__call` only runs when a method of $wrappedThing is invoked, right?)

Comment: Since the class is calling a method on itself, there's no real point for you to hook into. You'd need to take the entire class apart and replace every method with your own wrapper method; I'm not even sure this is feasible in PHP without a metric ton of bending over backwards. Again, a practical example would be good. There are probably design patterns that address your actual problem better than your current approach.